# How to host Wi-Fi on Raspberry Pi 3 for local SSH connection

Tags: pi-3, wifi, ssh

I've got a Raspberry Pi 3 B and I'd like to be able to remotely control it even when I can't establish a connection to any Wi-Fi router.

I'm using my Android phone as a remote access device, it has some SSH tools that should work in such a scenario, but the problem is with creating an access point for both devices to connect to.

So I was wondering, is it possible to create an access point **using the on-board** Wi-Fi that would allow my Android phone to connect to it and SSH into the Pi? At the same time I want my other USB Wi-Fi adapter to continue capturing network packets for example.

The idea is to use one Wi-Fi adapter as an access point for my Android device for the SSH connection and the other for some other unrelated network activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm sorry for not doing more thorough research before asking, but I've spent quite a few hours trying to find something and I couldn't find anything that would even remotely seem to work.

Just after I've asked, **I've noticed a similar question on SE** that didn't really answer my problem, but **it coincidentally linked to a [page that has solved my problem](https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/).** The guide was really easy to follow and could have been done with basic copy-pasting, unlike the ones I've tried before, making it completely foolproof.

I've tested connecting to my RPi from my Android phone and it works neatly. Both application that I use for RPi control, RasPi Check and JuiceSSH, work just as expected.